# AnyLogic findAll facility within certain distance from people and return best facility

Tags: anylogic, agent, findall

I am trying to use findAll function that takes two arguments: collection, condition. My collection will be facilities (Pharma) but condition is based on population distance. After finding all, I want to choose best (service) one. So far, I fried following approach. But an error and probably on condition in findAll; saying method is not applicable.... Could anybody help with this? or any other ideas?

```html
Pharma nearest = this.getNearestAgent(main.pharmas);
for (int i=0; i<main.people.size(); i++){
    Person p = main.people.get(i);
    if (p.getConnectionsNumber()>0){
        List <Pharma> x = findAll(main.pharmas, p.agentsInRange(100));//[Problem is here]
        Pharma y = top(x, s->s.serviceQuality);
        return y;
    }else{
        return nearest;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try `List  x = findAll(main.pharmas,p -> p.agentsInRange(100));`

Comment: See comment above. You are writing your Lambda syntax wrong.

Comment: Thanks. I cannot use p->p (redeclare), as I used p as var for people. So, I used r instead of p. In my code, my intention was: find all facilities (pharmas), such that they are within 100 meters of people(p). I tried your suggestion as: r->r.agentInRange(100) and have an error [Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<capture#1-of ? extends Pharma> to boolean]

Answer (score 1):

The find all function in AnyLogic requires you to use a predicate as the second argument for find all.

As per the comments you need to use

`x = findAll(main.pharmas,p -> p.agentsInRange(100))`

You can read more about using predicates here - https://www.theanylogicmodeler.com/post/using-predicates-in-anylogic

Comment: Is that predicate need to be related to the agent in first argument only? or can we make it by adding other agents? For instance, in my case, first argument: collection pharma agents, in second argument, I want to say "pharma agent in range of 100 meters of people agent". My purpose is: find all pharma within the 100 meter of people (p) and return a list <Pharma> x.

Comment: It should then be something like `x = findAll(main.pharmas, e -> e.distanceTo(p) < 100)`
Find all the pharmas where the distance from pharma (e) to Person (p) is less than 100 meters

Let me know if it works then I will update my answer

Comment: I think that's the right approach and it should work. But I am getting an error says: "This method must return a result of type Agent". For your information, I have created a function (Type: Agent) in People agent tab where I wrote this code and call it in state chart. I think I am making mistakes in x and y. If true, function will return y (which is type of Pharma agent, and it's coming from x, which is a list of Pharma). Could you please help, why the error is occurring? Thank you so much.

Comment: The compiler is just warning you that your function might not return anything. If main.people.size() == 0 then the for loop will never be entered and then the function returns nothing. So simply add `return null;` as the last line in the functuion

Comment: Error is gone. But, it's every time assigning to the nearest pharma. Instead of for loop, I used if-else and now I am getting the expected results. Thank you so so much for your help. If you will edit your answer, I will click as it solved my problem.

Comment: I am really glad you managed. Are you saying you used a if-else instead of the main for loop?

Comment: Yes. I don't know why the loop wasn't working (although there was no error), but if-else solved my problem. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code that solved my purpose. I wanted that there is a certain percentage of possibility that some people may go beyond the nearest facility for some reasons like better service quality.

```js
Pharma nearest = this.getNearestAgent(main.pharmas);
if (this.getConnectionsNumber()>0){
    List <Pharma> x = findAll(main.pharmas, l->l.distanceTo(this)<400);
    Pharma y = top(x, s->s.serviceQuality);
    if (randomTrue(0.4)){
        return y;
    }else{
        return nearest;
    }
}else{
    return nearest;
}
```